# Array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32'). Safe rule

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation

Why am I getting this error:

```
Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

When running this block of code:

```
quantity_list = df2['Qauntity'].tolist()
date_list = df2['Date'].tolist()

interpol = interpolate.interp1d(y = quantity_list, 
                                x = date_list)

ynew = interpol(quantity_list)
plt.plot(date_list, ynew)
```

**Line that produced error is:**

```
ynew = interpol(quantity_list)
```

Can it be connected with **memory reducing** in the head of all notebook?

*Part of mem. reducing code for variables in code above*:

```
#memory reducing
dtypes = {
    'Date': 'object',
    ...
    'Quantity': 'float32'
}

def reduce_mem_usage(df, verbose = True):
    ...
    return df


numerics = ['int8', 'int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
numerical_columns = [c for c, v in dtypes.items() if v in numerics]
categorical_columns = [c for c, v in dtypes.items() if v not in numerics]
```

This `dtypes` I imply for dataset when upload file to python.

**Important:**

Also I change `'Date'` from `'object'` to `'datetime64[ns]'` with `df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])`

- `np.array(quantity_list)` produce `float64` dtype
- `np.array(date_list)` produce `<U10` dtype

If i do the same date transformation out of code body, i recive `'<M8[ns]'` dtype.

*What kind of magic is it?*

Pandas interpolate function works fine, but pandas interpolate and scipy interpolate produce different result (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8796), and i need scipy's result.

Comment: Instead of `.tolist()`, try using `.values.astype(np.float)`. Does it still give you error?

Comment: To help us, show which line produced the error, may even the full traceback.  Also it may help to see `df.dtypes`.  `interpolate` will turn the argument lists into arrays, so I suggest testing `np.array(quantity_list)` and `np.array(date_list)`.  What shape and dtype does those produce?

Comment: `.values.astype(np.float)` does not help, but arise 
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01.01.2018'`

Comment: Ok `np.array(quantity_list)` produce `float64` and `np.array(date_list)` produce `<U10`. The shape is the same.